# Left And Right Android Navigation Drawers Overlapping Each Other

Tags: android, onclicklistener, togglebutton, navigation-drawer, android-homebutton

I have two navigation drawers in my app enabled by two icons on the left and right side respectively. Now my right side icon is a menu item so I am able to toggle both the navigation drawers via `onOptionsItemSelected`.

The problem I am having is that when I open the right drawer and then I open the left drawer, they overlap. I would like to know how to close the right drawer when I click the nav drawer button on the left hand side (The probable home button next to the application icon). Is there a click listener for that button like the menu Item?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: can you tell me How did you set navigation drawers on both side with an actionbar icon.

Comment: Refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861755/drawerlayout-double-drawer-left-and-right-drawers-simultaneously

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. Initially, `the ActionBarDrawerToggle` Button (Home Button) is also a menu item. Thus, when we call:

`mDrawerLayoout.onOptionsItemSelected()` we can put the code inside there.

Here is full the code for that:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (myDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        if (myDrawerLayout.isDrawerVisible(navDrawerRight) != false) {
        myDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(navDrawerRight);
    }
        return true;
    }
```

Notice I've put `myDrawerLayout.isDrawerVisible(View drawer)`. That is because `isDrawerOpened` only works when the drawer is fully opened or closed. It's better to use `isDrawerVisible()` as it works when the drawer is in any state, opened, closed or in between.

Hope this helps someone out there.