# Navigationdrawer on a fragment

Tags: android, user-interface, fragment

I have a main activity with a navigationdrawer on it to switch between multiple fragments. On one of these fragments I want to show another navigationdrawer on the right side.
What's the best solution to achieve that?

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861755/drawerlayout-double-drawer-left-and-right-drawers-simultaneously

Comment: It's not my case! I want to implement the left one on the activity and the right one on a specific fragment!