# Disable animation of drawer icon in double navigation drawer for right drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I have a [Double Navigation Drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861755/drawerlayout-double-drawer-left-and-right-drawers-simultaneously)

I have two problems.

1) The navigation drawer icon on the left (3 bars) animate when opening or closing the navigation drawer on the right.

2) I do not know how to add the icon to the right and have it animate only for the right drawer.

Comment: I too would like to know this. I know you can prevent the animation by overriding the onDrawerSlide method, but then icon just jumps over rather than animate.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell Have you checked out the [ActionBarDrawerToggle source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.java)? It's the class that animates the action bar icon, assuming you're following the [example in the docs](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#OpenClose).  It should be pretty straightforward to duplicate that for left/right behaviour; adding the icon for the right side might be the tricky part.

Comment: @AdamS Yeah I've got the icon on the right... easy peasy. But the OnDrawerSlide override that I'm doing only prevents the animation... The icon now just jumps to the left. https://gist.github.com/ChaseFlorell/10519029

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to override the onDrawerSlide method of ActionBarDrawerToggle and set the **slideOffset to 0** if the drawer is right drawer. So this would disable the animation of the navigation drawer image [image] for right drawer.

```
  @Override
  public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) 
  {
        if(drawerView!=null && drawerView == rightDrawerListView){
              super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, 0);
        }else{
              super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
        }
  }
```

This worked for me similar to Google+.

Comment: This worked for me, plus I had to add `super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, 0);` to the end of my `onDrawerOpened()` method, to prevent it from snapping open after the drawer animated.

Comment: That worked for me too, adding    if (drawerView != null && drawerView == navDrawRight.getView()) {
                    super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, 0);
                } to the end of the onDrawerOpened()

Comment: If i call `openDrawer(mDrawer)` in the activities `onCreate()` the icon starts off to the side, Anyone know a fix for this?

Comment: I tried this. I am getting error about no method `onDrawerSlide` in `super` class. Why? I am using v7 ActionBar. I think this is the problem.

Comment: Tried. But there is no toggle icon for right drawer.