# Drawer Toggle in right Drawer

Tags: android

I am creating drawer layout with both right and left menu as it worked fine but i need to stop toggling drawer icon when i open right menu . i am puzzled in it Please help.
 Thanks in advance.

```
switch(item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.add_member:
        if(chk==0){
            drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED,Gravity.RIGHT);
            chk=1;
            if(drawer.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT))
            {
                //ActivityCompat.invalidateOptionsMenu(Main.this);
                drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED,Gravity.RIGHT);
                    drawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
                    drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                    sh=1;

            }
            else{
                drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                sh=1;
            }
        }
        else if(chk==1){
            drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED, Gravity.RIGHT);
            drawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
            chk=0;

        }
        break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check answer in this link [Disable animation of drawer icon in double navigation drawer for right drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21867293/disable-animation-of-drawer-icon-in-double-navigation-drawer-for-right-drawer)

You can extend ActionBarDrawerToggle and override onDrawerSlide() method to set the slideOffset to 0 in the rightDrawerListView