# How do I make an app drawer on Right side as well as the Left? Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-actionbar

So far I've managed to make a app drawer on the left but I don't know how to also place one on the right, similarly triggered by another button on the action-bar. How can I do this?

My code so far is below:
**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // Within which the entire activity is enclosed
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

    // ListView represents Navigation Drawer
    ListView mDrawerList;

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle indicates the presence of Navigation Drawer in the action bar
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // Title of the action bar
    String mTitle="";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = (String) getTitle();

        // Getting reference to the DrawerLayout
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_list);

        // Getting reference to the ActionBarDrawerToggle
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle( this,
            mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,
            R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close){

                /** Called when drawer is closed */
                public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }

                /** Called when a drawer is opened */
                public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                    getActionBar().setTitle("Select a river");
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }
        };

        // Setting DrawerToggle on DrawerLayout
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        // Creating an ArrayAdapter to add items to the listview mDrawerList
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getBaseContext(),
            R.layout.drawer_list_item ,
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.rivers)
        );

        // Setting the adapter on mDrawerList
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Enabling Home button
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // Enabling Up navigation
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // Setting item click listener for the listview mDrawerList
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                View view,
                int position,
                long id) {

                    // Getting an array of rivers
                    String[] rivers = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.rivers);

                    //Currently selected river
                    mTitle = rivers[position];

                    // Creating a fragment object
                    RiverFragment rFragment = new RiverFragment();

                    // Creating a Bundle object
                    Bundle data = new Bundle();

                    // Setting the index of the currently selected item of mDrawerList
                    data.putInt("position", position);

                    // Setting the position to the fragment
                    rFragment.setArguments(data);

                    // Getting reference to the FragmentManager
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

                    // Creating a fragment transaction
                    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

                    // Adding a fragment to the fragment transaction
                    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, rFragment);

                    // Committing the transaction
                    ft.commit();

                    // Closing the drawer
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    /** Handling the touch event of app icon */
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /** Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);

        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**RiverFragment**

```
public class RiverFragment extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Retrieving the currently selected item number
        int position = getArguments().getInt("position");

        // List of rivers
        String[] rivers = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.rivers);

        // Creating view correspoding to the fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);

        // Getting reference to the TextView of the Fragment
        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_content);

        // Setting currently selected river name in the TextView
        tv.setText(rivers[position]);

        // Updating the action bar title
        getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle(rivers[position]);

        return v;
    }
}
```

Activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/drawer_list"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Have  `android:layout_gravity="end"` for ListView

Comment: When I change that, the app just crashes. I'll add the xml file(prior to changes) to the above.

Comment: please see this:

its work for me 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547277/how-to-set-navigation-drawer-to-be-opened-from-right-to-left?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

Add two components, one for the right side and another for the left.
Use:

```
android:layout_gravity="start" (Right side)
android:layout_gravity="end" (Left side)
```

note that they will be inverted for RTL languages.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/dlMenu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <!-- Main content -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flMainContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- Left Drawer Layout -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

    <!-- Right Drawer Layout -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

References: 
[DrawerLayout Double Drawer (Left and Right Drawers simultaneously)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861755/drawerlayout-double-drawer-left-and-right-drawers-simultaneously) 
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: Just noticed the comment above, you misplaced the tag. It is supposed to go in the ListView not the DrawerLayout. see answer above.

Comment: Although I change my xml to mirror the above. It still looks exactly the same

Comment: Ok, so what is your intended behavior? With the above XML you will get two lists, one from the right and another from the left. But you must still write the view, listeners and whatnot for each.

Comment: That's the bit that I'm stuck on, I was wanting the same button that's on the left to appear on the right to trigger the right drawer etc.