# How to add item in right drawer in android

Tags: java, android

I created simple application in android. In my app I'm using left drawer as well as right drawer also. I added data list in left drawer but I want to add some data list in right drawer also. and add Drawer toggle right side also. What should I do?

Please any one help!
Thanks in advance!!!

My code here:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private ListView mRightDrawerList;
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    CustomDrawerAdapter adapter;

    List<DrawerItem> dataList;



    //private String valid_email;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SharedPreferences pref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        getScreenResolution();
        // validation();
        // IF NOT SIGNEDUP then start loginActivity, else searchActivity
        if (pref.getInt(getString(R.string.signedupflag), 0) == 0) {
//            Intent loginIntent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
//            startActivityForResult(loginIntent,1);
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            LoginFragment fragment = new LoginFragment();
            transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
            transaction.commit();
        } else {

        }

        UserAccount usr = new UserAccount();

        dataList = new ArrayList<DrawerItem>();
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        // mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
        mRightDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.right_drawer);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
                GravityCompat.START);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);

        // First time app usage should check for the user login
        pref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        //If user already logged in then get user name and show search screen
        if (pref.contains("name")) {
            String userName = pref.getString("name", "");
            // Add Drawer Item to dataList
            dataList.add(new DrawerItem(true)); // adding a spinner to the list - 0

            dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Wallet")); // adding a header to the list - 1
            dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Balance", R.drawable.ic_balance)); // - 2

            dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Profile"));// adding a header to the list - 3
            dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Personal", R.drawable.ic_account));
            dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Work", R.drawable.ic_work));
            dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Address", R.drawable.ic_home));
            dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Vehicle", R.drawable.ic_car));
            dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Preference", R.drawable.ic_pref));

            dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Other Option")); // adding a header to the list
            dataList.add(new DrawerItem("About", R.drawable.ic_action_about));
            dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Settings", R.drawable.ic_action_settings));
            dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Help", R.drawable.ic_action_help));
        } else { // Show the sign-up/login screen. Get Name, Email and Mobile
            dataList.add(new DrawerItem(true));
            //dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Wallet")); // adding a header to the list - 1

            dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Other Option")); // adding a header to the list
            dataList.add(new DrawerItem("About", R.drawable.ic_action_about));
            dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Settings", R.drawable.ic_action_settings));
            dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Help", R.drawable.ic_action_help));
        }

        adapter = new CustomDrawerAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_drawer_item,
                dataList);

        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);


    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [DrawerLayout Double Drawer (Left and Right Drawers simultaneously)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861755/drawerlayout-double-drawer-left-and-right-drawers-simultaneously)

Comment: That user ask different question.. I have different doubts