# Open DrawerLayout by click on the button in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want use two `DrawerLayout`s in one `Activity`. One of them opens on the left side and the other of them opens on the right side. They should open after a click on the `ToolBar`.

For example : if I click the left button on the `ToolBar`, it opens the left `DrawerLayout` and if click the right button on the `ToolBar`, it opens the right `DrawerLayout`.

Please see these images to understand my meaning.

my XML code :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/DrawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/search_hint"
        tools:context=".Main_Page">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            layout="@layout/app_toolbar" />

        <com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout.SmartTabLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/viewpagertab"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"
            android:background="@color/primaryColor"
            android:clipToPadding="true"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            app:stl_defaultTabTextColor="@color/search_hint"
            app:stl_defaultTabTextHorizontalPadding="18dp"
            app:stl_defaultTabTextSize="15sp"
            app:stl_distributeEvenly="true"
            app:stl_dividerColor="@color/transparent"
            app:stl_dividerThickness="0dp"
            app:stl_indicatorColor="@color/black_20"
            app:stl_indicatorCornerRadius="18dp"
            app:stl_indicatorGravity="center"
            app:stl_indicatorInterpolation="smart"
            app:stl_indicatorThickness="36dp"
            app:stl_underlineColor="@color/transparent"
            app:stl_underlineThickness="0dp" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/viewpagertab">

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


        <co.aenterhy.toggleswitch.ToggleSwitchButton
            android:id="@+id/toggle"
            style="@style/ToggleSwitchButton" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/main_drawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_main__page"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header_drawer_main"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/primaryColor"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/primaryColor"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

java code :

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
TextView mTitle = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
mTitle.setText("title");
Drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.DrawerLayout);
mNaviView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.main_drawer);
mNaviView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, Drawer, toolbar, R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer) {

    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        if (con.isOnline()) {
            new get_menu_info().execute(public_username);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
        super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);

    }
};
Drawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
mDrawerToggle.syncState();

ImageView e1 = (ImageView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.right_tool);
e1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
    }
});
```

LogCot Error :

```
10-15 10:44:31.130    7061-7061/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.tellfa.smsbox, PID: 7061
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No drawer view found with gravity RIGHT
            at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.openDrawer(DrawerLayout.java:1322)
            at com.tellfa.smsbox.activities.Main_Page$5.onClick(Main_Page.java:210)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4764)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19844)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5349)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: There is a NavigationDrawer sample in the sdk, go check it

Comment: @TimCastelijns, this text is your help ?!!!! tnx dear friend!!!!! please help me Fully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your drawers are `leftDrawer` and `rightDrawer` respectively, you should be able to use

```
drawerLayout.openDrawer(leftDrawer);
```

to [open](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#openDrawer(android.view.View)) the left drawer,

```
drawerLayout.closeDrawer(rightDrawer);
```

to open the right drawer

```
drawerLayout.closeDrawer(leftDrawer);
```

to [close](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#closeDrawer(android.view.View)) the left drawer, and

```
drawerLayout.closeDrawer(rightDrawer);
```

to close the right drawer, respectively.

#### Update (code posted)

Use

```
Drawer.closeDrawer(mNaviView);
```

and

```
Drawer.closeDrawer(mNaviView);
```

See also [DrawerLayout Double Drawer (Left and Right Drawers simultaneously)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861755/drawerlayout-double-drawer-left-and-right-drawers-simultaneously).

Answer (score 2):

You can open or close your drawer with the code below.

```
/**
* For your right drawer
*/
drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT); 

drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);

/**
* For your right drawer
*/
drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT); 

drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should put the following in a click listener for the Toolbar icon:

```
drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
```

See the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#openDrawer(int)) for more info.

Comment: @ydstsh you don't have a DrawerLayout with Gravity.RIGHT, you've set it to Gravity.START in your layout file.

Answer (score 2):

For the Activity XML, you just add another View using `android:layout_gravity="end"`, and you interact with the right one the same as you would with the left one.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<!-- The main content view -->

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- The left navigation drawer -->

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/list_background"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

<!-- The right navigation drawer -->

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:background="@color/list_background"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```