# How to make DOUBLE navigation drawers left and right like Viber (with custom content)

Tags: java, android, xml, navigation-drawer

hello guys can you help me achieve the double drawers like the image bellow or like Viber app , (i know how to make custom content i only need the left and right drawers )

i found an example library here https://github.com/jfeinstein10/slidingmenu but its already old fashioned (they used ActionBarSherlock)

here this image with red and blue drawers with custom content 
i really wants to achive it just like that :

[double drawer image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXXsX.jpg)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/17861755/115145 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/19083574/115145

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DrawerLayout Double Drawer (Left and Right Drawers simultaneously)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861755/drawerlayout-double-drawer-left-and-right-drawers-simultaneously)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it using this tutorial it helped a lot 
http://updateunlimited.blogspot.com/2015/12/double-sided-nav-drawers.html