# Prevent DrawerLayout from opening the right side when closing the left side?

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout, android-drawer

I have a DrawerLayout with two drawers, one on the left and one on the right side.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <fragment        
        android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/leftFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left|start"/>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/rightFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right|end"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The problem is that sometimes when I swipe left to close the left drawer, it also opens the right one.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening? I'm thinking maybe I could block the opposite side from opening until both sides have been closed for at least X milliseconds or something, but I have no clue how to go about it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861755/drawerlayout-double-drawer-left-and-right-drawers-simultaneously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lock and UnLock the drawer from opening and closing based on drawer status

Code for LeftSide Drawer

```
mDrawerLayoutLeft.addDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            //lock the right side drawer when open the left drawer
            mDrawerLayoutRight.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
             //unlock the right side drawer when close the left  drawer
            mDrawerLayoutRight.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
        }

    });
```

Code for right side drawer

```
mDrawerLayoutRight.addDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            //lock the left side drawer when open the right  drawer
            mDrawerLayoutLeft.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
             //unlock the left side drawer when close the right drawer
            mDrawerLayoutLeft.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
        }

    });
```

There is other property for lock drawerLayout with gravity.

**Lock and unlock with Gravity.START**

**UNLOCK**

```
mDrawerLayoutLeft.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED, Gravity.START);
```

**LOCK**

```
mDrawerLayoutLeft.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED, Gravity.START);
```

**Lock and unlock with Gravity.END**

**UNLOCK**

```
mDrawerLayoutLeft.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED, Gravity.END);
```

**LOCK**

```
mDrawerLayoutLeft.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED, Gravity.END);
```

Comment: Hmm, but I'm using the same DrawerLayout for both the left and right side? Is it possible to lock one side only?

Comment: Updated the question to include the XML.

Comment: can you please also update java content,how you setup two drawer?

Comment: Ok great! Your previous answer actually made me implement something  similar already. Based on `drawerView.getId()` I'm choosing which of the drawers to lock. Something like `private int getOppositeDrawerEdgeGravity(View drawerView){
            return drawerView.getId() == R.id.leftFragment ? Gravity.RIGHT :Gravity.LEFT;
        }` and then `public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            ((DrawerLayout) drawerView.getParent()).setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED, getOppositeDrawerEdgeGravity(drawerView));
        }`. Seems to work great.